How i can get the login user Business Unit and Cost Center from active directory?
Is it possible to get the login user Business Unit and Cost Center from active directory inside our canvas app?

You call a SharePoint API to get that for you using Power Automate.
This is part of the URL
_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='CostCenter')?@v=%27i:0%23.f|membership|@{triggerBody()?['text']}%27
Your propertyName might be different than CostCenter so check "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties" in your browser for that property name
Repeat the HTTP request in flow for the Business Unit.

